Changing the order of operations in geometry nodes
I'm working on a reusable orbit animation controlled through geometry nodes, the point is to animate a planet orbiting around a sun, then possibly to add other planets or moons orbiting those planets. The problem is that to get the result I want I have to use 3 Transform geometry nodes in a row.

The first one with Z rotation input controls the planet rotating around its axis. The second one with the Y rotation input controls the axial tilt, and the third one with the translation input controls the orbit animation.
When I have all of these inputs plugged into only one Transform geometry node, I'm getting bad results, like the planet rotating around a vertical axis instead of a tilted one and the orbit tilt angle getting added to the axial tilt angle.
I have found this solution in using 3 Transform geometry nodes in this order, but I would like to ask if there is a simpler or more elegant solution.

Yeah, this is just the nature of rotating using Euler rotation. All 3D apps have to pick an order to resolve Euler rotations, XYZ, ZYX, etc. Trying to do all 3 at once can lead to unexpected results. If you're in 4.2 you could try using the matrix transform node. But otherwise you have to specify the order like you're doing here. More info in this post.

@Jakemoyo I already knew that, that's how I figured out this ugly solution. I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it. But thanks anyway :)

Perhaps you can save CPU time using Combine Transform nodes with just a single Transform Point node at the end ? An other approach based on the transformation sequence (Scale, Rotation X, Rotation Y, Rotation Z, Translation) could be to start with a Rotate Rotation node to combine Rotation Z with Rotation Y, then to insert a Rotation to Euler node and to plug the output in a single Transform Geometry node.

@StefLAncien I'm still on 4.0 so I don't have those nodes. Also I want this to be compatible with as many versions of Blender as possible.

The proposed approach is based on nodes available since Blender 3.5. It takes advantage that a Transform Geometry node is applying first Scale, then Rotation and eventually Translation. Because in GeometryNodes modifier, Euler rotation is around X, then Y and eventually Z, it has to be modified to rotate first around Z then around Y. To do so, a Rotate Euler node is used.

1. The dark pink frame is a copy of the graph shown in the question, with 3 Transform Geometry nodes.
2. The dark green frame is the optimized graph with a single Transform Geometry node.
3. Toggling the switch Optimized demonstrates that the output geometry is the same.
4. For timing purpose, a Point Cloud can be used to stress the modifier, instead of the default cube. Results show that the green frame is consistently more than two times faster than the pink one.

works really well, thank you.
